# Non-linear Model vs Linear Model for a dataset

Tags: regression, linear-model, nonlinear, law-of-large-numbers

I have a time series dataset for a city. The dataset contains rainfall amount and the number of repairman requests to a company. The company has 20 shops in different blocks of city and the rainfall data is also individually available for all 20 block. One point to consider is that rainfall is seasonal , hence when there is a rainfall in one block there is a high probability that there will be rainfall in some other block. Also it is assumed that a person in a given block will always place a request in the shop present nearest to him

I am trying to establish a relationship between the amount of rainfall and the number of repairman requests in that city at a block level.

I am getting good results when I model the aggregated data for the whole city using a linear model. In contrast when I model the data on individual block level using linear model, the results are not that good. Hence I have to use non linear models when establishing a relationship on block level.

What I want to do is to try to justify the use of non linear model instead of linear model for modelling relationship at a block level. One method which I feel could provide the justification is that 'law of large number' is not applicable at a block level of city but is applicable when the whole city is considered as a single unit.

Is this justification correct? Or do I need a different justification?
What sort of analysis do I need to perform  to support the justification?

Comment: How are you dealing with the dependence in the data? What sort of model are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make a hypothesis that the amount of rainfall can be used to predict the number of repairman requests.

When treating the whole city as a single unit I am using a linear model Y ~ mX + c.

When predicting on a block level, I am using random forest model (non-linear) predicting Y with predictor X

Comment: What exactly are you referring to as dependence? Dependence of one block on another, or dependence of requests on rainfall?

Comment: Dependence over time. You have repeated measures. This violates the assumptions of linear regression and other regression methods. Two common ways of dealing with it are multilevel models and time series methods (ARIMA and so on). Your model Y ~ mX + c is inappropriate, unless I am missing something. Random forests are likely to also be inappropriate, but I am not certain and it may depend on exactly how you are implementing them.

Comment: The hypothesis I am trying to make is that for any week w in any location l, the amount of rainfall R(w,l) is a good predictor of the number of requests in that week in that location Q(w,l). 

Hence I am not exactly treating it as a timeseries. I mean Q(w,l) is independent of both Q(w-1,l) and Q(w,l2)

Comment: The last statement seems rather suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I am too "young" to join the discussion in the comments, so I will post my ideas and guesses as an answer.

I think there are better ways to estimate model fit (and hence justify it) than appealing to asymptotic laws. For example, you can fit a model an inspect the prediction errors. Or you can do cross validation and figure out which of the models has a better predictive capabilities.

In your case, it seems that you have already (somehow) determined that pooled linear model is inadequate and want to go to block level. I don't know why it didn't work, but I can guess - you have too little data on a block level and individual-block-regressions model overfits. If that is the case, the decision to go to individual-block-nonlinear-model is slightly suspicious, as you could overfit even more. Maybe you could consider an approach like hierarchical regression, which regularizes individual regressions.

When you are happy about the block level fit, then it is only appropriate to plot errors over time, and look if time is significant predictor. If it is, you can include it into the model as well.

Comment: What I mean by aggregated data is that I have aggregated data over all locations i.e sum of all requests from all blocks and sum of rainfall in all blocks. The linear model describing a relationship between this summed up data is a good fit. 
But if instead I use a hierarchical model or a simple linear model treating each block separately but training just a single model for all, then the results are bad.  

My non-linear model also treats all blocks separately, but I have a single model trained and tested on combined data of all blocks and it works well.

Comment: So it seems that you have already figured out the goodness of fit part. In such case I don't think there is a need for a further justification of the model, unless you want to understand yourself why regularized linear models were inadequate compared to random forests. I don't think I can say anything clever with regards to that, especially without seeing the data.